# Using `geom_line()` with X axis being factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
hist <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date() + 0:13,
                   counts=1:14)
```

I want to plot the total count against weekday, using a *line* to connect the points.
The following puts *points* on each value:

```
hist <- transform(hist, weekday=factor(weekdays(date),
                                       levels=c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')))
ggplot(hist, aes(x=weekday, y=counts)) + geom_point(stat='summary', fun.y=sum)
```

When I try to connect them with a line (`geom_line()`), ggplot complains about only having one data observation per group and hence is not able to draw a line between the points.

I understand this - it's trying to draw one line for each weekday (factor level).

How can I get ggplot to just pretend (for the purposes of the line only) that the weekdays are numeric? Perhaps I have to have another column `day_of_week` that is 0 for monday, 1 for tuesday, etc?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, specifying `group=1` and adding a `stat_summary()` layer should do the trick:

```
ggplot(hist, aes(x=weekday, y=counts, group=1)) +
geom_point(stat='summary', fun.y=sum) +
stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line")
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! What is the purpose of `group=1` (why 1? what does that do?)

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. [here (ggplot2 documentation)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html)

Comment: In case you want to plot multiple lines at once, you should specify `group=variableWhichDefinesLines'

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me very easily was:

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(X, Y)) + 
       geom_point() +
       geom_path(group=1) +   
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

`group = 1` lets ggplot know that you want to treat all the observations as part of the same group, and will therefore draw the line. The `theme` line is just for a cleaner look. You can delete it if you want.